# Invalid type: CampaignInfluence

Tags: apex, soap-api

I am getting error while querying on object **CampaignInfluence**

```
 List<CampaignInfluence> caminlst = 
                  [select id,Contact.Id,Opportunity.Id,Campaign.id from CampaignInfluence]
```

> API Version : 43

Does it require to enable any salesforce feature ?

If yes how to enable that ?

Salesforce Reference : [CampaignInfluence Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_campaigninfluence.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to enable [Customizable Campaign Influence](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=campaigns_influence_customizable.htm&type=5) to use this object.

There are various steps you need to follow to enable this.

- Configure Customizable Campaign Influence
  Allow your marketing department to attribute revenue from an opportunity across multiple campaigns when you enable Customizable Campaign Influence.
- Enable Users for Customizable Campaign Influence
  Be sure the sales and marketing users who plan to use Customizable Campaign Influence have the Sales User permission set assigned with the Campaign Influence permission enabled.
- Add Customizable Campaign Influence to Page Layouts
  Let your marketing users see the campaigns that influence each opportunity and the results of each campaign.
- Create a Custom Campaign Influence Model
  To implement a custom influence attribution model, first add a model in Setup with a few clicks. Then create a set of triggers and processes that add campaign influence records and assign them to the model. Work with partners if you want help implementing a custom model.
- Designate a Default Campaign Influence Model
  Change which of your campaign influence models displays data on opportunity and campaign detail pages.
- Lock a Campaign Influence Model
  Prevent users from adding or editing campaign influence records for a campaign influence model by locking the model. Locked models can only be accessed via the API.

[Set Up Customizable Campaign Influence](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=campaigns_influence_customizable_setup_parent.htm&type=5)

Comment: In 2nd point "Enable Users for Customizable Campaign Influence..", 
How can we do that ?
I am using System Admin Profile. 

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=campaigns_influence_customizable_enable_users.htm&type=5